# XMonad startup on different workspaces

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I want to startup some applications in different workspaces(it is important) on xmonad start. So, I wrote following `startupHook`:

```
startupApps :: [String]
startupApps = ["konsole", "emacs", "firefox", "gvim", "konsole"]

startupSpawn :: X ()
startupSpawn =  zipWithM_ id (map (spawnOn . show) [1..])  startupApps
```

But, it spawns all apps in first workspace. It seems to be part of more general problem -- if I start application, it get workspace not when it actually started, but when it loaded. 
So, if I start firefox on WS1, then switch to WS2, firefox will spawn on WS2.

Still, what can I do about my intention?

Comment: Have you checked out this answer? http://superuser.com/questions/478498/start-applications-on-specific-workspaces-in-xmonad

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`manageHook`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/XMonad-ManageHook.html) to tell xmonad to move certain applications to certain desktops.

```hs
myManageHook = composeAll . concat $ [
    [ className =? "Firefox" --> doF (shiftToWs 2) ]
  , [ className =? "gvim" --> doF (shiftToWs 3) ]
  -- and so on
  ]
```

The `className`s might vary, though.

Comment: When would this run, though? Would it run on every action? Because it'd be quite annoying not to be able to shift windows on purpose ...

Comment: @NoonSilk: No, it only applies when you *open a new window*. Afterwards you can arbitrarily move a window around.

Comment: Note that `concat [[x],[y]]` is equal to `[x,y]` so example is a bit cluttered.

Comment: @MatveyAksenov: You have a point, but there must have been a good reason to put this in my config. Quite strange.