# Start applications on specific workspace if not yet started there

Tags: haskell, window, x11, xmonad

In short: when I switch to workspace *X*, I want some programs to autostart, but only if they're not already started.

This is different from [XMonad startup on different workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13279791/3132718) as I don't want to move windows to specific workspaces (like always moving xterm to workspace 2).
This doesn't work for me, either: [xmonad spawn on startup in different workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10976044/3132718). I don't want all applications to start immediately as I log in, also this won't autostart e.g. xterm if I close it and switch to workspace 2 again.

---

Enough about what doesn't work, here is what *does* work:
<sub>(almost)</sub>

In my workspace list I hold touples with the workspace name and a list programs to start when I switch there:

```
myWorkspaces = [ ("VIM", ["gvim"]), ("TERM",[myTerminal ++ " -e tmux"]) ]

-- In my keybindings:
[ ((mod4Mask, key), loadWorkspace workspace cmd)
  | (key, (workspace, cmd)) <- zip [xK_1..] myWorkspaces
]
```

I defined a function to switch to a workspace and spawn the given programs:

```
loadWorkspace :: String -> [String] -> X()
loadWorkspace workspace commands =
    do windows $ W.greedyView workspace
       mapM_ spawn filtered_commands
           where filtered_commands :: X [String]
                 filtered_commands = filterM isNotOpen commands

                 isNotOpen :: String -> X Bool
                 isNotOpen command = return True
```

(For some reason `mapM_` requires the second argument to be a *String* instead of *[String]*. I want to map `spawn` over the strings in *filtered_commands*, any idea why this doesn't work?)

The last missing piece is the `isNotOpen` function, which should search the `className`s of the windows in the current workspace and return whether `command` is already there.

---

I find it extremely hard (compared to other languages and technologies) to search for the XMonad way to do things. For this case I could only find how to get the windows in the current WS - https://superuser.com/a/852152/481701. Ok, I think, this gives me a Window object, I can query it for some attributes.

But no. The Window is actually... alias for `Word64`!!! Ok, I think. Google *xmonad get window attributes*. Nothing. *xmonad get classname from window id*. Nothing. *xmonad window information*. And a dozen other ways to say something similar - no helpful results. All I get is the xmonad homepage, the FAQ, or "Xmonad configuration tips".
I tried these in *hayoo!*, too, and the closest I could get was "fromClassName - Colorize a window depending on it's className.". Haha.

## So, how can I get a window's className (or any other attributes) outside of *ManageHook*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might like [dynamic projects](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Actions-DynamicProjects.html) or [topic spaces](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Actions-TopicSpace.html) as prebaked alternatives. They don't do *exactly* what you propose, but perhaps one of them is close enough to still be useful, and require less configuration work.

> I want to map spawn over the strings in filtered_commands, any idea why this doesn't work?

Yep, you need to lift `mapM_` to handle a monadic argument (as opposed to a monadic function or return value). Thus:

```
filtered_commands >>= mapM_ spawn
```

Or, since you are already in a `do` block:

```
result_of_filtered_commands <- filtered_commands
mapM_ spawn result_of_filtered_commands
```

> So, how can I get a window's `className` (or any other attributes) outside of `ManageHook`?

Look at [the source of `className`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.13/docs/src/XMonad-ManageHook.html#className):

```
className = ask >>= (\w -> liftX $ withDisplay $ \d -> fmap resClass $ io $ getClassHint d w)
```

You can take just the argument to `liftX` as an `X` action rather than a `Query` action. The key function is [`getClassHint`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/X11-1.8/docs/Graphics-X11-Xlib-Extras.html#v:getClassHint) from the X11 package. That package also offers access to other attributes of windows.

Comment: Thank you very much for every part of your so detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

Install wmctrl

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
```

And create a script (in this example thunderbird on the second workspace (`-t 1`)):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

 (thunderbird &)  & sleep 5 && 
sh -c "wmctrl -i -r `wmctrl -l | grep Thunderbird` -t 1"
```

To know your application name on wmctrl you can view it by taping on your terminal :

```
wmctrl -l
```

And replace it with the correct name in the script.

Be carrefull with the capital letter ("Thunderbird" not "thunderbird") !!

Other example with firefox on the 3d workspace (`-t 2`):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
(firefox &)  & sleep 5 && 
sh -c "wmctrl -i -r `wmctrl -l | grep Firefox` -t 2"
```

## Bonus :

Here is the command to execute at start-up :

```sh
sh -c "thunderbird  & sleep 5 && wmctrl -i -r `wmctrl -l | grep Thunderbird` -t 1"
```

Work on Debain 10 with Cinnamon. But should work for all